# Sql query to print all Department Names and the name of the newest employee in that department

Tags: mysql, sql

Am Kind of new to MySql and am trying to retrieve a query but got struck for some time.

Sample data set:

```
   CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `EmpId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EmpName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DeptId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Jod` date NOT NULL,
  `Salary` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `employee` (`EmpId`, `EmpName`, `DeptId`, `Jod`, `Salary`) VALUES
(1, 'ABCD', 1, '2015-02-23', 50000),
(2, 'EFGH', 1, '2016-04-11', 40000),
(3, 'HIJK', 2, '2016-05-22', 35000),
(4, 'LMNO', 3, '2016-05-22', 30000),
(5, 'PQRS', 3, '2016-06-03', 30000);

CREATE TABLE `dept` (
  `DeptId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeptName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `dept` (`DeptId`, `DeptName`) VALUES
(1, 'Sales'),
(2, 'Account'),
(3, 'Support');
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3347ebd03943c0f824bf58f5b7334a40)

where i am trying to execute the queries.

Now I need a query to print all Department Names and the name of the newest employee in that department

So as per my understanding the desired result must be

```
 Dept Name         Employee Name
 ---------         -------------

 Sales              EFGH
 Account            HIJK
 Support            PQRS
```

I have already done some query ,The link is attached above . [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3347ebd03943c0f824bf58f5b7334a40)

How to get the desired result,Any help aprreciated.

Comment: You can do that using ROW_NUMBER and partition. 
Here's an article discussed elaborately.
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+ using `ROW_NUMBER`, we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d.DeptName, e.EmpName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeptId ORDER BY e.Jod DESC) rn
    FROM dept d
    INNER JOIN employee e ON e.DeptId = d.DeptId
)

SELECT DeptName, EmpName
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

On MySQL 5.7 you can try this:

```
SELECT d.DeptName, 
       (SELECT e.EmpName FROM employee e WHERE e.DeptId=d.DeptId ORDER BY e.Jod DESC LIMIT 1) AS EmpName
FROM dept d
```

[image]

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccb0ee5a41bf8197f95bdc3128b5d30b)

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: @Mark . . . I removed `DISTINCT`.  It is not needed at all -- under the reasonable assumption that department names are unique (as in the sample data).  This also works in MySQL 8+ and is likely to have the best performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for the update, yes, you are completely right.

Comment: @Mark . . . I couldn't upvote with the `DISTINCT`, which is why I edited the question.